# java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively error

Tags: clojure, java-io

I am trying to program in Clojure and am using the stand alone IDE Counterclockwise. I do not know if this is an error with my computer or with the program itself. I uninstalled this program and reinstalled it because there were some issues with libraries, so I thought reinstalling it would ensure the correct installation of libraries. When I open a new copy of Counterclockwise and try to run some of my programs, it gives me this error when running clojure's REPL

```
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
at leiningen.javac$javac_options.invoke(javac.clj:66)
at leiningen.javac$run_javac_subprocess.invoke(javac.clj:115)
at leiningen.javac$javac.doInvoke(javac.clj:139)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at leiningen.core.main$resolve_task$fn__3029.doInvoke(main.clj:189)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:29)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:230)
at leiningen.core.eval$run_prep_tasks.invoke(eval.clj:43)
at leiningen.core.eval$prep.invoke(eval.clj:57)
at leiningen.core.eval$eval_in_project.invoke(eval.clj:323)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:167)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at leiningen.repl$repl.doInvoke(repl.clj:263)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at leiningen.core.main$resolve_task$fn__3029.doInvoke(main.clj:189)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:29)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:230)
at leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke(main.clj:234)
at leiningen.update_in$update_in.doInvoke(update_in.clj:34)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:573)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:440)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:193)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at leiningen.core.main$resolve_task$fn__3029.doInvoke(main.clj:189)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:29)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:230)
at leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke(main.clj:234)
at leiningen.update_in$update_in.doInvoke(update_in.clj:34)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1138)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:465)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:248)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at leiningen.core.main$resolve_task$fn__3029.doInvoke(main.clj:189)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:29)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:230)
at leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke(main.clj:234)
at leiningen.update_in$update_in.doInvoke(update_in.clj:34)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:2482)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:496)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:328)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at leiningen.core.main$resolve_task$fn__3029.doInvoke(main.clj:189)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:29)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:230)
at leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke(main.clj:234)
at leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__3092.invoke(main.clj:303)
at leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke(main.clj:290)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
at ccw.leiningen.main$_main.doInvoke(main.clj:47)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:2422)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:496)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:328)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:335)
at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:3204)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:510)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:367)
at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

This giant mass of an error, I have read, apparently refers to the folders that my projects are in. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this issue as I have no idea what the problem is as all this is foreign to me, Thanks!!!

Comment: I am getting the same error. This link helped me (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojuredev-users/gYuFnFPqVOY). I updated counterclockwise within eclipse and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem in my windows system, and solved it by making sure that the `%TEMP%` was pointing to a real existing folder.

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
```

**Example**: 
In my setup I am using `git-bash`for command-line, so I checked for the presence of the `%TEMP%` environment by this command:

```
echo $TEMP
```

This resulted in `/d/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp`. Then I verified that this did not point to an existing folder by

```
cd $TEMP
```

which resulted in failure. I fixed the problem by

```
mkdir /d/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different case as I need to bypass `lein.bat` and just run the lein executable jar to launch lein. I got things working from the command line, but not when I was launching it from a Java `ProcessBuilder`, so the temp folder must have been different for these cases. You can actually specify the temp folder you want by setting a java System property: `java.io.tmpdir`

In my case, the following worked to launch a lein app:

```
java -cp leiningen-2.5.3-standalone.jar -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Temp clojure.main -m leiningen.core.main run
```

(the above is the equivalent of running `lein run`)